# YouTrack Import Issues from XML file unexpected API response

Tags: ruby, rest-client, youtrack

I am trying to import **issues** from XML file to this path:

```
/rest/import/{project}/issues
```

It is giving me error saying with 500 Error Code : `userService has not been initialized.`

It is a Ruby application and I am using RestClient for put request.

This is my code,

```
RestClient.put('https://*********.com/youtrack/rest/import/CC/issues', 
                File.new("issue.xml", 'rb'), 
                "Cookie" => @cookie ,
                "Content-Type" => "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
           ){ |response, request, result, &block|

      case response.code
        when 200
          # debug
          print_response( response ) if @print_responses
          return response
        when 423
          return response
        else
          return response
      end
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with my request. 
It seems like YouTrack bug. HAve anybody experienced that before or any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like YouTrack's issue.
I would recomend you to post an issue in YouTrack project. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23jt#newissue=yes or contact to youtrack-feedback@jetbrains.com

Comment: That's what I thought. I already did but haven't heard back yet. Thanks